# Cancel a running task when leaving view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using `.task` to fetch some data when entering a new view. I do this till it gets the data. This works fine if the call really returns the right data, if not and I close the view, I get an endless loop. This is my code:

```
VStack(){
        Form{
            Section("QR-Code"){
                if let cgImage = EFQRCode.generate(for: deviceId, watermark: UIImage(named: "LogoSmarterSoftware")?.cgImage) {
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)).resizable().frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                }
                /*Button("Login"){
                    //deviceId = "0B6B03F3-99E1-469F-BE1E-EA163EFE0963"
                }*/
            }
        }.frame(height: 180)
        
    }.task {
        users.removeAll()
        if (deviceId == "") {
            deviceId = x // Could change here
        }
        userId = ""
        employeeId = ""
        /*Task{
            await doHTTPUserCall()
        }*/
        while userId.isEmpty || employeeId.isEmpty{
            Task{
                await doHTTPUserCall()
            }
            print("test")
            do{
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 3_000_000_000)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            //deviceId = "0B6B03F3-99E1-469F-BE1E-EA163EFE0963"
        }
        
        
    }
```

If I exit the view without getting a right response, I get an endless loop saying

> CancellationError()
> test

> CancellationError()
> test

> CancellationError()
> test

> CancellationError()
> test

Is there any way of killing an existing task or am I missing something in my code?

Comment: By the way, why is `await doHTTPUserCall()` inside a `Task { ... }` block? And why are you sleeping at all?

Comment: @Rob I have no clue why it's in the task-block, thought it hast to be done like that. Going to change that now. The reason why I am sleeping is because I don't want to send a Request every time. I want it to pause in between the requests so my api don't get spammed.

Comment: OK, so you're throttling it. That's fine. But `Task { ... }` followed by `Task.sleep` risks having the next request starting before the previous one finished. But it's moot, as you'll be retiring the `Task { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is endless loop there. When view disappears task is cancelled, but cancelation handling is on our side

According to doc:

[image: demo1]

so it is needed at least to verify state, like

```
while !Task.isCancelled && (userId.isEmpty || employeeId.isEmpty) {
```

or call `checkCancellation` inside loop wrapping everything in `try/catch`

```
while userId.isEmpty || employeeId.isEmpty {
   try Task.checkCancellation()
```